# JSON Object Declaration in JS - manually construct string or declare object then convert

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Okay, so I've got some legacy code that constructs JSON objects by hand (makes the string).

```
var stringJSON = '{ "person": "'+userName+'", "code": "'+password+'" }';
request.write(stringJSON);
```

But I have since realized that this would work just the same by using object declaration.

```
var jsObject = { "person": userName, "code": password };
request.write(JSON.stringify(jsObject));
```

I mean it looks like the first way will be...trivially faster.  But the actual javascript object declaration way feels cleaner.  Is there any inherent advantage to either method?

Comment: I don't think there are any advantages of building your own string. Object notation is the way to go, that's where JSON comes from, **J** ava **S** cript **O** bject **N** otation

Comment: Yeah...there was definitely a moment of "wait...balls".  I guess I'll convert it all over just to save the embarrassment .